# ¿Por qué no genera una lista de archivos al utilizar la función exec() en un EXE en PHP/Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, windows

Buen día,

Estoy tratando de crear un pagina que ejecute un *exe, que este espera dos respuestas del usuario, uno es una IP y la otra es una contraseña.
[image: Captura de pantalla del programa]

La aplicación que quiero ejecutar con Laravel es un datadownload y se ocupa introducir dos datos para descargarlos: una IP y contraseña, y al introducir estos datos correctamente genera una lista de archivos en formato *txt. Ahora bien, lo que quiero hacer es replicar esto, pero en Laravel, sin que haya que ejecutar directamente el exe. Investigue y encontré que se puede hacer con exec() en PHP, sin embargo, no logro hacer que se creen los archivos. Al grabar la respuesta en una variable e imprimir sale que se están generando los archivos pero no pasa de ahí, pues voy a la carpeta y no hay nada.
Estoy tratando que se generen los archivos en la carpeta Storage que viene incluida en Laravel. Nota: El datadownload.exe genera los archivos.

Este es el código que estoy utilizando.

```
$data = storage_path('data\datadownload.exe').' < '.storage_path('data\production.txt');
$output = exec($data);
```

Que sería como si hiciera esto en cmd

```
C:\> datadownload.exe < production.txt
```

Donde production.txt tiene la IP y la contraseña

De antemano, muchas gracias.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar

```
$file = fopen("archivo.txt", "r");

fwrite($file, "Esto es una nueva linea de texto" . PHP_EOL);

fclose($file);

Storage::disk('public')->put('ruta-final', "archivo.txt");
```

o directamente guardando el txt

Comment: El detalle es que yo no creo los archivos, los crea el programa datadownload.exe, los crea de forma automática cuando la IP y la contraseña son correctas.

Comment: Entonces tienes que ver en que entorno esta corriendo tu .exe, y si tu task esta apuntando correctamente al archivo. 

Fíjate que tengas instalado IIS, en el servidor porque lo que hace laravel es intentar ejecutar el archivo dentro de su entorno. 

Si todo esta correcto lo ultimo que se me ocurre es que veas si no los esta guardando en la carpeta storage/tu ruta que donde salen tus archivos

Comment: Hasta donde se, el exe lo hicieron en R, y es de tipo consola. Y no, ese es el problema, no genera los archivos en ninguna parte. Genera los archivos si yo abro directamente el exe y pongo IP y contraseña o si en CMD pongo este comando "C:\> datadownload.exe < production.txt" donde dentro de production.txt esta la IP y la constraseña.

Comment: Los .exe se ejecutan en un entorno windows por eso tu servidor tiene que estar en IIS, si esta en centos, apache o algún otro basado en linux no lo va a ejecutar porque unix no es compatible. Tendrías que instalar una extensión a tu servidor para que sea capaz de ejecutar ese tipo de comando. Puedes ver que sistema esta corriendo tu servidor con esta linea ejecutándolo desde una conexión "ssh  uname -a" Si es un sistema windows te dira que el comando no existe y si es un linux te dará la versión.

Comment: Si quieres que te ayude de una forma mas especifica mándame un mensaje.

Comment: Por el momento, estoy trabajando en XAMPP en un entorno Windows, aunque al final, se instalara en un servidor Linux.

Comment: Ahí tienes tu problema, tu php se esta ejecutando dentro del servidor de apache, si tu pones en la terminal de windows php te dirá que el comando no existe porque no lo tienes instalado localmente. Por lo tanto cuando php intenta ejecutar en linea de comandos tu instrucción falla.

Comment: No, el comando en si no falla. De hecho al guardar la respuesta de la función exec() me dice que están creando los archivos, sin embargo, al revisar en carpeta no hay nada.